# I can't execute apps on the Linux Mint installation desktop

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, ssd

I am trying to install Linux Mint on a new SSD.  I copied the Linux Mint Xfce installation app to a USB drive and rebooted.  I can't execute the apps on the Linux Mint desktop - Installation icon, Firefox, etc. Single clicking will select the icon.  Double clicking does nothing.  Right clicking does not load a properties window.

I have used Ubuntu in the past with no problems.  I want to use a lighter weight version of  Linux.

(Laptop: Lenovo Ideapad i5.)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you did when you say that you "copied the Linux Mint Xfce installation app to a USB drive"?

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard of an app to install Mint. You say you have used Ubuntu previously. Did you install it yourself? I am not sure what level of experience you have and so I am guessing a little about the advice I think you seek. The download I use for Mint is an .iso file from the Linux Mint Download page. This needs to be written to the usb rather than copied to it. There is a ton of internet advice on how to do that eg with USB Image Writer in Mint or dd from the commandline. Then the computer should be restarted from the USB after you set BIOS or EFI to read the USB drive first. Please let me know if this is at all useful, or restate your question.
Cheers